# Format verification in SPIN

Tags: spin, promela

I learned Promela and Spin, but when I try verifying the model, these lines
are returned to me.

[image]

What do they mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you ran a Spin verification and your verification identified an error.  Your next step is to determine how the error occurred.  You do that by generating and examining the 'trail file'.

If you performed your verification as:

```
$ spin -a model.pml
$ gcc -o pan pan.c
$ ./pan
```

then examine the trail using the model.pml file with:

```
$ spin -p -t model.pml
```

Comment: After examining, the trail file. I did get the failed scenario or the text of failed assertion. What should I do next?

Comment: My objective is to generate TestCases for the failed scenarios? How can I generate counter examples?

Comment: The trail file tells you the exact path through your code/model that produces a violation of your correctness constraints.  You understand this path by carefully tracing it though step-by-step.  What you do next, depends on your goal - for example, if your model is of a real world system, then perhaps you found a real, actual problem.  Or maybe you found an error in your model; if so, fix the model and re-run the verification.  Sometimes the verifications can be *VERY* large; look into the `pan` options for `-i` and `-I`; they help reduce the size of the failed scenario trail file.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I have tried and did all the things. And the failed scenario from the trail helps me find the location of the error. There by finding counterexample for the same. And any ideas how can I automatically generate testcases for failed scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have a deadlock or other error in your model.

If you would post your complete console output, I could probably update this answer to give you more information!